# UWP App with multiple frames using the MVVM pattern

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

Is there any library / framework that could simplify Universal Windows Platform app development of the application that contains multiple Frames.

I mean, using [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net) or [BezySoftware MVVM-Navigation](https://github.com/bezysoftware/MVVM-Navigation) the application is highly tied to the idea of navigating between different pages that are hosted by single frame.

The UI I try to develop consist of multiple content frames (main, left, right) which content varies. I need something that will let me navigate easily between different views (by placing these views into appropriate frame) and provide the same features I would have with [BezySoftware MVVM-Navigation](https://github.com/bezysoftware/MVVM-Navigation), so:

- handling of the view model state persistence
- the ability to activate / query deactivate view models
- back button feature

Comment: The official guidelines is a page based navigation and using frame navigation may alienating for your app users, as even the Win 8.1/10 apps follow this paradigma. Also you can't use data templates with `DataType` on UWP/WinRT apps. And prism for winRT/UWP also do not support regions, that you usually use in WPF

Comment: I don't think there's an existing framework yet. This is a very special case and navigation is pretty much tied to your scenario. It already starts at IOC (Service locator has to know which NavigationService to inject, Navigation Commands have to be aware of the frame, etc.). I recommend just starting with a NavigationService that knows/is told in which frame the navigation should happen. Everything else will probably unveil itself in the process.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I started to introduce app specific navigation service which knows how to deal with different frames but it seems that I have lost all other mentioned MVVM-Navigation features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few different options:

1. Combination of a single navigation service injected into your view model AND user controls for areas that need to be repeated view to view (e.g. a tabs, status bars, etc).  With this route, every time you create a new view you would paste in the common user controls that need to appear.  You would also be able to expose bindable properties from said user controls.
2. Combination of `ContentControl`, `DataTemplate`, and `DataTemplateSelector` to load in either an entire view (`Page`) or fragments of XAML.  As one person pointed out you cannot use `DataType` attribute, instead you use the `DataTemplateSelector` class to do the mapping for you.  With this approach you can also use triggers to dynamically change the template (content) based on changes to properties on your view model and/or user interactions.
3. A mix between 1 and 2 above.

Answer (score -2):

I might right the whole thing right here, but it too lengthy. I just recommend you see this article to get your answer.

[MVVM patter in UWP](http://www.top5solutions.com/mvvm-pattern-uwp-windows-10-apps/)

Comment: The linked article doesn't answer the question, but more the basic meaning of MVVM.